# Trigonometric equation $2\sin^3(x) + 3 = \cos^2(x) + 5\sin(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having trouble solving this equation:

$$
2\sin^3(x) + 3 = \cos^2(x) + 5\sin(x)
$$

Some hint would be appreciated :) Thanks in advance!

Comment: $\cos^{2}x = 1 - \sin^{2}x$. Solve the resulting cubic equation.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** :
Use $$\cos ^{ 2 }{ x } =1-\sin ^{ 2 }{ x } \\ 3=3\cdot 1=3\left( \cos ^{ 2 }{ x } +\sin ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the identity $\cos^2(x)\equiv 1-\sin^2(x)$:

$$2\sin^3(x)+3=1-\sin^2(x)+5\sin(x)$$

Now, you can substitute $u=\sin(x)$ to obtain a cubic equation:

$$2u^3+3=1-u^2+5u$$
$$2u^3+u^2-5u+2=0$$

Now, you can solve the cubic equation.

Comment: Use the fact that $u=1$ is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x,
$$
the equation is equivalent to:
\begin{eqnarray}
2\sin^3x+3&=&1-\sin^2x+5\sin x\\
2\sin^3x+\sin^2x-5\sin x+2&=&0\\
2\sin^3x+\sin^2x-3\sin x-2\sin x+2&=&0\\
(2\sin^2x+\sin x-3)\sin x-2(\sin x-1)&=&0\\
(2\sin^2x-2+\sin x-1)\sin x-2(\sin x-1)&=&0\\
[2(\sin^2x-1)+\sin x-1]\sin x-2(\sin x-1)&=&0\\
[2(\sin x+1)(\sin x-1)+\sin x-1]\sin x-2(\sin x-1)&=&0\\
(\sin x-1)(2\sin x+2+1)\sin x-2(\sin x-1)&=&0\\
(\sin x-1)[(2\sin x+3)\sin x-2]&=&0\\
(\sin x-1)(2\sin^2x+3\sin x-2)&=&0\\
\sin x-1&=&0 \text{ or } 2\sin^2x+3\sin x-2=0\\
\sin x&=&1 \text{ or } \sin x=\dfrac{-3\pm5}{4}\\
\sin x&=&1 \text{ or } \sin x=\dfrac{1}{2} \text{ or } \sin x=-2\\
\sin x&=&1 \text{ or } \sin x=\dfrac{1}{2} \text{ because } \sin x \in [-1,1]
\end{eqnarray}
Solving the two equations we get
$$
x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi \text{ or } x=\dfrac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi \text{ or } x=\dfrac{5\pi}{6}+2k\pi \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Comment: I don't understand what you did between line 5 and 6.